# Apache Jmeter is not giving any error even we gave wrong credentials

Tags: jmeter, microstrategy

I am new to JMeter. I am using it for load testing for Microstrategy web dossiers. I am loading the users from CSV Config file. I have generated steps using Badboy software and exported as Jmeter file. I have added variables for userID and password. I have enabled "Retrieve all Embedded Resources". When I ran the testing. I observed that its giving same response even if password is wrong. taskProcs are giving connection closed error. I have searched with dossier ID in both the cases , I am able to see the request and response same even if password is wrong. Can you help me how to identify whether the credentials matched or not ? I would like to throw error when password didn't match ? I thought of adding Response Assertions but responses are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter automatically treats [HTTP Response Status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful. So if [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler returns status [200](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200) (or any other between 100 and 399) it's treated as success.

JMeter doesn't perform any checks for content, if you need to add explicit pass/fail criteria basing on the response body, presence or absence of certain text, sampler execution time, etc. you need to add a relevant [Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps/) and put the anticipated success criteria into the assertion.

Answer (score 1):

First JMeter doesn't generate any error codes or error messages itself, what it actually do is working as client and giving back what application sends to JMeter. 
I think first you have to make sure application works correctly, then check whether Jmeter scripts work correctly. For that add debug sampler before the API request and check whether variables username, password has evaluated correctly from the csv.

Comment: I have verified all the parameters both are same. Its working in web but its not working from jmeter. Application is working fine.

Comment: Are you sure JMeter reads the csv correctly and update the username, password on API request?